# how to overwrite existing file in ftp using wput.exe

Tags: ftp, batch-file

How can I force to always overwrite an existing file in ftp using wput?

Anyone? please provide the dos command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `-u` and `-nc` options while uploading.

For details check [the project's Sourceforge page](http://wput.sourceforge.net/wput.1.html).

Comment: The link states that with `-nc` a remote file being smaller than the local one will be overwritten. With `-u` a remote file having the same size as the local one is to be uploaded. What if the remote file is larger?